# Git rebase squash history

Tags: git

I am trying to squash all my previous commits in to one.

```
pick b4f3e443231232 first commit
s    b4f3e443243243 second commit
s    b4f3e44d324324 third commit
s    b4f3e4423434324 fourth commit
```

I am now getting a conflict that I am trying to resolve.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
validates :username,
  :presence => true,
  :uniqueness => {
  :case_sensitive => false
}
>>>>>>> b4f3e44...
```

I don't know which part do I have to keep,
which is the latest commit of the two ?
The head or the hash one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know which part do I have to keep

You'll have to choose the code you consider correct here.

> which is the latest commit of the two ? The head or the hash one ?

The `HEAD` points to the most recent/latest commit in the repository. The hashed part is the content for the specific commit identified by the hash.